# through/by being a good example

Tags: prepositions

I want to write: help them by/through being a good example. What is the right word, by or through?

Comment: They're both correct.

Comment: By being a good example sounds better than through being a good example.

Answer (score -1):

From the proverb:  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/example) (McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs)

> You will teach people more effectively by being a good example than
>   you will by telling them what to do.

My sense is that **by being an example** is most grammatical.